# Deleted /etc/mysql/... now unable to install or uninstall other software

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, mysql

I was messing around with my mysql install and was trying to replace it with a mariadb-server installation.
After using the typical commands for completely removing mysql I was unable to delete an old config. So in a moment of frustration I made the mistake of just sudo rm -r the mysql folder in /etc/.
Now my problem is whenever I try to make an installation of any other software or mysql I get from dpkg following error:

```
aniqui@Lenobuntu-Z50-60:/$ sudo apt-get autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libllvm9 libllvm9:i386 linux-headers-5.4.0-37 linux-headers-5.4.0-37-generic linux-image-5.4.0-37-generic linux-modules-5.4.0-37-generic linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-37-generic
  linux-modules-nvidia-440-5.4.0-37-generic
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 8 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 525 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 252879 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing libllvm9:amd64 (1:9.0.1-12) ...
Removing libllvm9:i386 (1:9.0.1-12) ...
Removing linux-headers-5.4.0-37-generic (5.4.0-37.41) ...
Removing linux-headers-5.4.0-37 (5.4.0-37.41) ...
Removing linux-modules-nvidia-440-5.4.0-37-generic (5.4.0-37.41) ...
linux-image-nvidia-5.4.0-37-generic: removing .ko files
Removing linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-37-generic (5.4.0-37.41) ...
Removing linux-image-5.4.0-37-generic (5.4.0-37.41) ...
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-37-generic
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-40-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-40-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-39-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-39-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Found Windows 10 on /dev/sda1
done
Removing linux-modules-5.4.0-37-generic (5.4.0-37.41) ...
Setting up mysql-server-8.0 (8.0.20-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Failed to stop mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not loaded.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "stop" failed.
update-alternatives: error: alternative path /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf doesn't exist
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-8.0 (--configure):
 installed mysql-server-8.0 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-8.0
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Apprently mysql is still installed but since I have delete the mysql folder Im unable to proceed with any other task.

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
maniqui@Lenobuntu-Z50-60:/$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 8.0.20-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))
maniqui@Lenobuntu-Z50-60:/$
```

Is there a way to clean dpkg listings?? In order to ignore that missing installer ?? I have already tried the typical commands:

```
apt-get autoremove
apt-get autoclean
apt-get purge
dpkg -r mysql-server-8.0
apt-get install -f
```

I keep receiving the error.
**Errors were encountered while processing:
mysql-server-8.0
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)**

Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have fixed the Issue.
The source is here: [dpkg-returned-an-error-code-1](https://itsfoss.com/dpkg-returned-an-error-code-1/)

Method 4: Remove post info files of the troublesome package was the one that helped me to fix the issue.

```
sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-* /tmp
sudo apt-get autoremove
```